# Edit with Elementor not loading

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Just took control of an elementor project from another guy and everything worked perfectly so far. But now everytime that I want to edit a page with elementor , it loads forever and the safe mode doesn't fix it.
I've deactivated every single pluggin and same story.
on the other hand I have this 503 error showing up.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same issue, but I solved it by disabling The Plus Addons for Elementor. Not sure what was causing the conflict though

Answer (score 1):

This can be of following issues,

1. If you are using cache plugin then clear all cache first.
2. Check if there is any elementor update available.
3. Mostly this issue occur when you use any elementor addon like essetional addons ect so try to deactivate them first and clear cache.
4. Goto General settings -> permalinks -> Check if the permalinks are set to Post types, if permalinks are already set to post types then first check set custom and change back to post type and save.
5. Goto elementor -> tools -> general -> Regenerate Files & Data & Sync Library. If it does not work then activate safe mode and try again.

Answer (score 0):

are you using latest version elementor if yes, then can you please rollback to Elementor 3.5 and check again. you can rollback from Elementor->Tools->Version Control (tab).

Answer (score 0):

The stability of Elementor can be affected by the PHP version you have installed. To avoid potential crashes, it's crucial to ensure that your PHP version is higher than the required minimum version. Checking your PHP version under system info and upgrading if needed will help maintain a smooth experience with Elementor.